# Intermediate Value Theorem Application; prove that function range is always positive

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Given that:
>
> 1) $f(x)$ is continuous for all $x$
>
> 2) passes through point $(1,2)$ that is $f(1) = 2$
>
> 3) $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x$
>
> Prove that $f(x) > x$ for all $x$

I think I'm in the right direction but please correct me if I'm wrong. Suppose $f(x)$ is actually $0$ for all $x$. This contradicts that $f(1) =2$ (given). Suppose $f(x)$ is not positive for all $x$. If this is the case then $x_0$ exists such that $x_0 \neq 1$ and  $f(x_0) = x_0 - c$ where $c > 0$.$\quad f(x_0)$ is continuous as well because $c$ is a constant hence continuous as well so of course $f(x_0) = x_0 - c$ is continuous too.  Since $x_0 \neq 1$ we have 2 different points on $x$ axis: $1$ and $x_0$. According to the intermediate value theorem there must be an $x_1$ between $f(1)$ and $f(x_0)$ such that $f(x_1) = x_1$. However this contradicts the given conditions that $f(x) \neq x$. Thus $f(x) > x$ for all $x$.

Especially I'm not sure if it's better to define a helper function $E(x)=f(x) -c$ or leave $f(x_0) = x_0 - c$.

Comment: This is by intermediate value theorem, not by mean value one

Comment: Define $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and use IVT to conclude that $g>0$: you know that $g(1)>0$, and suppose that there is $a$ such that $g(a)\le 0$. Then by IVT there must be $c$ between $a,1$ such that...

Comment: I don't understand why we suppose that there is an $a$ such that $g(a) \le 0$. Because there can be a function which does not cross $x$ axis at all and still $g(a)$ could be less than $a$.

Comment: If $g(a)\le 0$ then $f(a)-a\le 0$ i.e. $f(a)\le a$ so existence of such $a$ will mean there is a point such that $f(x)\le x$. Want to show this never happens. But $g(a)\le a$ means $g$ must cross $x$ axis at least once because $g$ is continuous, and $g(1)=1>0$ so $g$ takes values in $[0,1]$ between $x=a$ and $x=1$. Use IVT

Comment: I absolutely see the logic of your explanation. However I don't understand why my proof is not good. Because you're suggesting to use IVT in its practical version (that a function will have 0 values) however the way I see even without 0 values I can prove that $f(x) > x$ because otherwise it would have a $(x_1,f(x_1))$ point which contradicts the given.

Comment: I don't understand your proof at all. Most of what you said after you stated "suppose there is a point where $f$ is negative".  First why is there $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0-c$ where $c>0$? How is this deduced and relevant to the question? What exactly is condition on $c$? Further, saying $f(x_0)=x_0-c$ is continuous makes no sense, becasue this is just some real number, not a function.

Comment: Because we need to prove that $f(x) > x$ this means that there exists a real number $c>0$ such that $f(x) = x + c$. Thus in order to disprove this let's suppose that $f(x) = x - c$ this way $x$ would be bigger than $f(x)$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Okay, I think you should've said "suppose that there is a point $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)<x_0$", not that it is negative. But even then your proof does not work. IVT only tells you that for any $K$ between $f(x_0)=x_0-c$ and $f(1)=2$, there is some $x_1$ between $x_0$ and $1$ such that $f(x_1)=K$. This does not tell you that there is some $f(x_1)=x_1$

Comment: you're right I thought if $c$ exists that there's $f(c) = c$. Intuitively if we look at the graph (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qzipms5mcx) we do see that the only way there will be $f(x) < x$ is if $f(x)$ crosses $y=x$ linear function. And I think this can be proven via IVT but I can't think of the correct proof. anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the cleanest helper function is
$$
g(x) = f(x)-x
$$
You immediately know that

- 1)$g(x)$ is continuous since it is the sujm of two continuous functions.
- 2) $g(1)=1$ since$ f(1)=2$
- 3) For all $x$, $g(x) \neq 0$ since $f(x) \neq x$.

$g(1) > 0$.  Assume for some $x_0 >1$ that $g(x_0) \leq 0$.  then the intermediate value theorem says that at some point $x_1$ in the interval $[1,x_0]$, $g(x_1) = 0$, contradicting (3).  Similarly, if for some $x_0 < 1$ that $g(x_0) \leq 0$, then there is again some point $x_1$ in the interval $[x_0,1]$, such that $g(x_1)=0$, which is the same contradiction.

So $g(x)$ is never negative or zero, and thus $f(x)$ is never less than or equal to $x$.

Comment: thanks but why my version isn't good?

Comment: Also why does the fact that $g(x)$ is never negative or zero mean that $f(x) > x$? For example there could be $x = 5$ and $f(x) = 2$ in which case $f(x) < x$ and $f(x) > 0$.